# BuildRoot - accessing eth0 needs root privileges

Tags: networking, root, ethernet, buildroot

I've been building a number of BuildRoot images for an x86_64 single board PC I'm testing.  I am using the latest BuildRoot from git, and the latest 4.8.1 kernel.

I have everything working, except for some reason any access to Ethernet requires the user to be root, e.g. even a ping.  My board uses the Intel IGB driver.

What could be causing this?  My kernel config. is at http://pastebin.com/KXgrLRy7

Comment: Concerning `ping`, this could be related to missing capabilities. Running `getcap $(which ping)` should return `/usr/bin/ping = cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+ep`. If not, you could configure the capabilities with `setcap`.

Answer (score 1):

Add  user to `netdev` group

```
adduser user_name netdev
```

Reload `dbus`:

```
/etc/init.d/dbus reload
```

Comment: Unfortunately the netdev group suggestion didn't work, it may have on a Debian based system.  I think my problem is at a much lower level, the SBC vendor is looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

Final answer was that I had to suid root on the ping executable.